# How to remove the key and value from the disk store in geode?

Tags: disk, gemfire, geode

While using Apache Geode/Gemfire implementation, my requirement is to not only have the IMDG functionality but also I want to commit the values to disk-stores. In case, all of my Geode server go down, I would like to to bring them back and have a persistence key-values.

Now, when i remove a key from the cache, the key and value is removed from all the clustered cache (or say I use destroy mode for eviction action). However, the disk space is not reclaimed or reduced; so, if I continue to use persistence_overflow for regions, how should I clear up the disk space as well to accommodate new entries?

Again, i understand there is compact option, but then, i am not looking for compaction, i want to completely remove the key/value pair and reclaim the disk space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not configurable under the current implementation: each `GemFire/Geode` member configured with a `disk-store` creates the `oplog` file occupying whatever was configured through the `max-oplog-size` property, which defaults to `1GB`. During regular execution, obsolete operations are **only removed from the `oplogs` during compaction**, as explained in [Design Your Disk Stores](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/97/geode/managing/disk_storage/using_disk_stores.html#defining_disk_stores__section_0CD724A12EE4418587046AAD9EEC59C5).

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was presuming as its the same compact command in MongoDB as well.

Answer (score 0):

As Juan mentioned, compaction is the way that Geode frees up disk space.

You can tune the compaction to free up disk space more quickly at the expense of performance. You can decrease the max-oplog-size and increase the compaction-threshold to reclaim disk space faster.

For most use cases I would recommend leaving the compaction-threshold alone. The defaults are tuned for maximum write throughput and no more than 50% garbage on disk.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I wonder if there have been a configuration in the geode to remove the key value from the disk directly would have been great.
Something like, soft delete in the first actual transaction and then behind the scene lower priority thread, just going and claiming all the space on disk as per the configuration. So, more like self healing.